# Input.GetKeyDown calls a coroutine to put in 1st person but it blocks my character's movements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, coroutine, f5

In this script, I call a coroutine using Input; this coroutine allows that if we press F5, change the view of our character that we see in 3rd person mode to 1st person mode and if we press F5 again, it will replace the view. Only, by using input.GetKey and not input.GetKeyDown the coroutine will read several times which gives an ugly result. But when I use Input.GetKeyDown, and I'm in 1st person mode (the basic view is in 3rd person) my character's movements are blocked: I can't move forward, backward, jump etc... error in the script ?

If you want to test on unity, just download the file on this link https://github.com/TUTOUNITYFR/unitypackages-jeu-survie-2022-tufr/blob/main/Episode01/personnage-et-environnement.unitypackage then in the AimBehaviourBasic script, replace all the code with:

`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// AimBehaviour inherits from GenericBehaviour. This class corresponds to aim and strafe behaviour.
public class AimBehaviourBasic : GenericBehaviour
{

    public Texture2D crosshair;                                           // Crosshair texture.
    public float aimTurnSmoothing = 0.15f;                                // Speed of turn response when aiming to match camera facing.
    public Vector3 aimPivotOffset = new Vector3(0.5f, 1.2f,  0f);         // Offset to repoint the camera when aiming.
    public Vector3 aimCamOffset   = new Vector3(0f, 0.4f, -0.7f);         // Offset to relocate the camera when aiming.

    private int aimBool;                                                  // Animator variable related to aiming.
    public bool aim;                                                      // Boolean to determine whether or not the player is aiming.

    // Start is always called after any Awake functions.
    void Start ()
    {
        // Set up the references.
        aimBool = Animator.StringToHash("Aim");
    }

    // Update is used to set features regardless the active behaviour.
    void Update ()
    {
        // Activate/deactivate aim by input.
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.F5) && !aim)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ToggleAimOn());
        }
        else 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.F5) && aim)
        {           
            StartCoroutine(ToggleAimOff());         
        }
    }

    // Co-rountine to start aiming mode with delay.
    private IEnumerator ToggleAimOn()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        // Aiming is not possible.
        if (behaviourManager.GetTempLockStatus(this.behaviourCode) || behaviourManager.IsOverriding(this))
            yield return false;
        // Start aiming.
        else
        {
            aim = true;
            int signal = 1;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            aimCamOffset.x = Mathf.Abs(aimCamOffset.x) * signal;
            aimPivotOffset.x = Mathf.Abs(aimPivotOffset.x) * signal;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            behaviourManager.GetAnim.SetFloat(speedFloat, 0);
            // This state overrides the active one.
            behaviourManager.OverrideWithBehaviour(this);
        }
    }

    // Co-rountine to end aiming mode with delay.
    private IEnumerator ToggleAimOff()
    {
        
        aim = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        behaviourManager.GetCamScript.ResetTargetOffsets();
        behaviourManager.GetCamScript.ResetMaxVerticalAngle();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        behaviourManager.RevokeOverridingBehaviour(this);
    }

    // LocalFixedUpdate overrides the virtual function of the base class.
    public override void LocalFixedUpdate()
    {
        // Set camera position and orientation to the aim mode parameters.
        if(aim)
        {
            behaviourManager.GetCamScript.SetTargetOffsets (aimPivotOffset, aimCamOffset);
        }
    }

    // LocalLateUpdate: manager is called here to set player rotation after camera rotates, avoiding flickering.
    public override void LocalLateUpdate()
    {
        AimManagement();
    }

    // Handle aim parameters when aiming is active.
    void AimManagement()
    {
        // Deal with the player orientation when aiming.
        Rotating();
    }

    // Rotate the player to match correct orientation, according to camera.
    void Rotating()
    {
        

        // Always rotates the player according to the camera horizontal rotation in aim mode.
        Quaternion targetRotation =  Quaternion.Euler(0, behaviourManager.GetCamScript.GetH, 0);

        float minSpeed = Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, targetRotation) * aimTurnSmoothing;

        // Rotate entire player to face camera.
        
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, minSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    // Draw the crosshair when aiming.
    void OnGUI () 
    {
        if (crosshair)
        {
            float mag = behaviourManager.GetCamScript.GetCurrentPivotMagnitude(aimPivotOffset);
                GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - (crosshair.width * 0.5f),
                                         Screen.height / 2 - (crosshair.height * 0.5f),
                                         crosshair.width, crosshair.height), crosshair);
        }
    }
}
```

`

Now you can test, press play and then press F5: the camera will change position but if you try to move (les touches : Z,Q,S,D, escape or arrowUp, arrowDown etc..) absolutely nothing will happen: here is my problem... Sorry for my bad English I am French ; )

Comment: I still think that since you `behaviourManager.OverrideWithBehaviour(this);` .. the name suggests that other behaviors .. such as moving the player ... are not applied anymore

Comment: How should I reapply them?

Comment: I would probably make `AimBehaviourBasic` inherit from your player movement in order to extend it instead of overwriting it ... absolutely not sure how your `behaviourManager` system works there

Comment: Sorry, I have not enderstand 

Answer (score 0):

Using coroutines like this will mess up your code because both coroutines can run almost at the same time, for example:

- If you press F5 the first time `ToggleAimOn()` will be executed but before it get's finished you can press F5 again and call `ToggleAimOff()`, and since coroutines are async, that means they can run at the same time so it will create a real messed up behaviour

What you can try is to have another flag beside `aim` that will check if a coroutine is running like this:

```
private bool IsCoroutineActive = false;
void Update ()
{
    // Activate/deactivate aim by input.
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.F5) && !IsCoroutineActive  && !aim)
    {
        StartCoroutine(ToggleAimOn());
    }
    else 
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.F5) && !IsCoroutineActive && aim)
    {           
        StartCoroutine(ToggleAimOff());         
    }
}

// Co-rountine to start aiming mode with delay.
private IEnumerator ToggleAimOn()
{
    IsCoroutineActive = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
    // Aiming is not possible.
    if (behaviourManager.GetTempLockStatus(this.behaviourCode) || behaviourManager.IsOverriding(this))
    {
        IsCoroutineActive = false;
        yield return false;
    }
    // Start aiming.
    else
    {
        aim = true;
        int signal = 1;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        aimCamOffset.x = Mathf.Abs(aimCamOffset.x) * signal;
        aimPivotOffset.x = Mathf.Abs(aimPivotOffset.x) * signal;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        behaviourManager.GetAnim.SetFloat(speedFloat, 0);
        // This state overrides the active one.
        behaviourManager.OverrideWithBehaviour(this);
    }

    IsCoroutineActive = false;
}

// Co-rountine to end aiming mode with delay.
private IEnumerator ToggleAimOff()
{
    IsCoroutineActive = true;
    aim = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
    behaviourManager.GetCamScript.ResetTargetOffsets();
    behaviourManager.GetCamScript.ResetMaxVerticalAngle();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
    behaviourManager.RevokeOverridingBehaviour(this);
    IsCoroutineActive = false;
}
```

Comment: thank you ! I'll try this when I have time...

Comment: alternatively you could also use `StopCoroutine` to interrupt the current one before starting the new one

Comment: I just added one more line of code inside the "ToggleAimOn()" method, so please use the updated version.

Comment: It works halfway: the view doesn't stutter but my character's movements are still blocked...